# How to ConvertObject or roArray to String

Tags: roku, brightscript

Is there any way available for convert the roarray/object to string. I checked my variable datatype using Type(Myval). It's roArray and I'm trying to convert with string. I [tried](https://community.roku.com/t5/Roku-Developer-Program/Convert-Object-or-roArray-to-String/td-p/255548) using add the genaraliutilities in my channel and use ToStr() in Code. and Before Adding Utilities Simply, I write ToStr() But both way doesn't work.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Join()** method to convert the **roArray** object into string. e.g.

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
str = arr.Join("")
```

If you need to add any separator between array elements, you can specify in **Join()** method. For converting the array object into string, the array elements must be of type string.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to convert both, `roArray` and objects (assuming you're referring to `roAssociativeArray`), you have to use the `FormatJson(:Object:Integer)` method. See [docs](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/language/global-utility-functions.md#formatjsonjson-as-object-flags--0-as-integer-as-string).

Example:

```
obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
arr = ["a", 1, "b", 2.5]
objStr = FormatJson(obj)
arrStr = FormatJson(arr)
?"objStr "objStr ' Prints: "{"a":1,"b":2}"
?"arrStr "arrStr ' Prints: "["a",1,"b",2.5]"
```